# Repeated window invalidation in GTK+: failure after several steps

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, invalidation

I have a timer which calls a method (`perform_step`) every second. `perform_step` does some computation and invalidates my window. This works well initially but after a small number of iterations the on_expose_event of the window isn't triggered. From debugging I discovered the window invalidation method had been called, but the event handler isn't entered.

Any ideas what might cause this? Here are some things I've discovered that might be helpful:

- When the computation in `perform_step` is shorter, things break down after less iterations.
- Things break down after the same number of iterations every time.
- Moving the mouse over the window keeps things from breaking down. If I constantly move the mouse over the window things will run forever. It seems to "reset" the counter. If things would break down after 10 iterations and on the 9th iteration I move the mouse over the window, things then break down on the 19th iteration.

Here a code snippet:

```
bool SimDisplay::on_button_press_event(GdkEventButton* event) {
  Glib::signal_timeout().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &SimDisplay::perform_step), 1000 );
}

bool SimDisplay::perform_step() {
  world->step();
  //on the last iteration this is called but on_expose_event is never reached
  get_window()->invalidate(true);
}

bool SimDisplay::on_expose_event(GdkEventExpose* event) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: What if you do your counting /without/ using `signal_timeout`? Does it work correctly then?

Comment: @senshikaze I've tried many ways to do the computation without using `signal_timeout` and have found that any method which should run forever breaks down after a small number of iterations. For example, I've tried (unsuccessfully) calling `perform_step` at the bottom of 'on_expose_event`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `on_button_press_event()` is missing a `return` statement; make sure all your handlers are returning the proper thing.